# WebSerial on windows, No devices found

Tags: windows, google-chrome, web, serial-port

I have tried WebSerial API on Ubuntu and Windows both.

On Ubuntu 20.04, it works well.
But my customer use Windows 7. He just got 'no devices found'.

Test app is https://googlechromelabs.github.io/serial-terminal/

Chrome version is 89.

Serial is `cp2102` USB to serial converter of Silicon Labs.

I tried it on my VirtualBox windows7x86 with binding `/dev/ttyUSB0` to `COM1`.
Windows legacy terminal programs works well, but chrome WebSerial result is same as 'no devices'.
My friend's Windows 10 chrome 89 also show same result.

Could anybody help this?

Thanks

Comment: I think the reason is https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2099238 
If driver don't support GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT, Windows chrome don't show up devies.
Should I build https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/serial/VirtualSerial? or wait https://github.com/google/web-serial-polyfill/issues/9

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1015074&q=component%3ABlink%3ESerial&can=2

I think this is exact reason.
I will try again on my windows labtop at home.